# Amazon SimpleDB: Define auto_increment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to define auto_increment at properties of an attribute in my domain.

But I couldn't do it anywhere. Is that possible? If so, where can I check how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to code your own auto increment feature.  Take a look at [conditional puts](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/).  If you're looking to build a unique identifier rather than a counter, keep UUIDs in mind as they're much easier and more efficient than hitting the database unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

An below example shows you can auto increment the attribute names where value is greater then 1024, that is to be uploaded.

```
if (fieldvalue.length() >= 1024) {
                                int index = 1;
                                while (fieldvalue.length() >= 1000 && vlist.size() < 254) {
                                    String value = new String(fieldvalue.substring(0, 1000).getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");

                                    ItemAttribute objItemAttribute = new ItemAttribute(fieldname+index, value, fieldreplace.booleanValue()); 
                                    vlist.add(objItemAttribute);
                                    fieldvalue = new String(fieldvalue.substring(1000).getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
                                    index++;
                                }
                            }
```